# NFA-style representation of regexps which includes AND

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions, matching

I'm looking for a regexp matching strategy that supports conjunction and which is based on an NFA-style machine.  I know how to handle conjunctions using a DFA, or using Brzozowski's approach, but for various reasons, I can't use Brzozowski's technique and bump into state explosion when using a DFA.

I know about the cross-product construction to compute the intersection of two NFAs, but there as well: while the state explosion is not as severe as when going through a DFA, it is sometimes still too severe for my needs, so I'd like an NFA-like representation that lets me build the cross-product "on the fly", kind of like "Thompson's NFA" matching constructs the DFA states on the fly.

Comment: What have you tried?  What approaches have you considered and rejected?  You can convert a regexp into a NFA using standard methods, and there are standard methods to take the conjunction (intersection) of two NFAs and to match a string against a NFA.  So what's the issue?  We expect you to do a significant amount of research/self-study before asking and to show us in the question what research you've done and what approaches you've considered.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I've clarified the alternatives I've considered by also mentioning the cross-product construction.

Comment: Why do you want to close this question?  I am not sure about the motivations for it, but it does make sense to me.

Comment: @babou,  At the time that I posted my comment, the question consisted of 2 sentences (the first 2 sentences)... hence the call for more details before we could usefully answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit  difficult to answer you because you state that you are using NFA
to do the matching. NFA being non deterministic, that leave the
interpretation technique open, depth first, breadth first, or
variants. So I am trying to give you an answer that should fit any
interpretation of the NFA. This technique should be applicable to
other constructions than intersection.

You have 2 NFAs, $A_i=(Q_i,\Sigma,\delta_i,\hat q_i, F_i)$ for
$i=1,2$. The intersection is a NFA $A=(Q,\Sigma,\delta,\hat q, F)$
defined as usual for the intersection, notably with $Q=Q_1\times
Q_2$.

The idea of the technique is to implement the transition function
$\delta$ not as a table, but as a function $\delta: (Q_1\times
Q_2)\times\Sigma\to 2^{(Q_1\times Q_2)}$, that calls in turn the
function $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$.

```
function delta((q1,q2),a)
{ return (delta1(q1,a), delta2(q2,a))}
```

This is to be read as a non deterministic program, in the sense
described in [this answer to How does one formulate a backtracking
algorithm?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41601/how-does-one-formulate-a-backtracking-algorithm/41605#41605) That means that, in actual interpretation, the functions
are actually returning sets of results, one by one if backtracking, or
together if breadth-first.

The rest is up to the way you translate non-determinism into
determinism, either by a compiler, or by hand. It can be done
depth-first or breadth first. It can even use memo function to compute
incrementally and remember the part of the transitions of the
automaton $A$ that is needed for the string at hand, and possibly keep
it for future strings to be matched.

Of course, if your automata are DFAs, this is much simpler to read as
usual deterministic functions (possibly implemented by tables for
`delta1` and `delta2`. Then memoisation of `delta` will construct
incrementally the table for the cross product.

The can be seen as an incremental construction, or as a generalisation of call by need. Rather than building the automaton up-front, you build the parts you need when you need them (and you can even forget some, if you run out of space). This can also be used for the powerset construction, and in many other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to run your two NFAs in parallel, then see if they both accept.

Apparently, you have two NFAs, $M_1,M_2$.  You have an input string $x$.  You want to see whether $x$ matches their conjunction.

A good solution is to first check whether $x$ matches $M_1$, then check whether $x$ matches $M_2$, and accept $x$ only if matches both.  Note that this is much more efficient than using the product construction to compute a NFA $M$ for the conjunction of $M_1$ and $M_2$, then matching $x$ against $M$: $M$ will have quadratically many states, so the running time of matching $x$ against $M$ will be quadratic (in the size of $M_1,M_2$), whereas the running time of matching $x$ against $M_1,M_2$ separately will be linear (in the size of $M_1,M_2$).